# Groupby a dataframe on column A and column B and sum column C based on few values of column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

For a dataframe which looks like the below

```
A     B     C
foo   1     2
foo   3     3
bar   3     4
bar   3     4
else  4     5
else  2     1
```

We need to groupby the dataframe based on column A and sum values in column B only if the values in column A = 'foo' or 'bar', but sum all the values of column c.

So the result should look like:

```
A    B   C
foo  4   5
bar  6   8
else     6
```

The code I am using the moment is:

```py
def sum_hours(df, values):
    return df.loc[df['A'].isin(values), 'B'].sum()

grouped = df.groupby(['A'], as_index= False).agg({'A': 'first', 'B': lambda x: sum_hours(x,['foo', 'bar'], 'C':'sum')
```

This is not giving the correct output and also taking a very long time.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
data = {'A': {0: 'foo', 1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'bar', 4: 'else', 5: 'else'},
 'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 2},
 'C': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

make columns `B` to `NaN` after `groupby` by using `where`

**Code**

```
a = ['foo', 'bar']
(df
 .groupby('A', sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
 .assign(B=lambda x: x['B'].where(x['A'].isin(a))))
```

output:

```
     A      B   C
0   foo     4.0 5
1   bar     6.0 8
2   else    NaN 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Mask values of `B` before grouping and aggregating:

```
df.assign(B=df['B'].where(df['A'].isin(['foo', 'bar']))).groupby('A',sort=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
        B  C
A           
foo   4.0  5
bar   6.0  8
else  0.0  6
```

Comment: You could use `as_index=False` on the `groupby` to return the exact result OP wanted...